# js cross domain solution - without confermation from other domain

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

I have an application (running on domain A) which needs to send a soap request (or web service) to another domain (domain B).

I need a solution that does not ask permeation from B (its not mine and I can't control it).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web service on your own domain that calls the service from domain B server side.  Essentially your service would just be a proxy.

Comment: we don't have access from our server to the other domain.

Comment: I don't have access to the other domain from my server, the other domain is on the clients network behind a firewall.

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on what domain B offers. If you don't control domain B and we don't know what domain B is, then we can't help you with specifics. However, generally, domain B would have to provide data fitting one of these requirements:

- A [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/) service
- The ability to be read by [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

JSON-P is easy — either website B provides it or it doesn't. Chances are it doesn't, since you're asking here.

YQL is a bit more convoluted. You need to authenticate with the YQL service itself, but then you make a database-like query to them, *their* servers scrape domain B, and then return the results to you in XML or JSON format. This will be a bit of work on your part (and may not be possible, depending on how domain B is structured) — [this article](http://christianheilmann.com/2009/08/25/tutorial-scraping-and-turning-a-web-site-into-a-widget-with-yql/) does a good job of explaining the principles.

Comment: JSON-P does not support POST requests. YQL requires me to add code on Domain B. I don't have an option to add scripts on that domain and it is behind the clients firewall.

Comment: I read 'request' and assumed you'd be `GET`ting your information from B. You'll have to be more specific with your question if we're to work out if this is anything more than a generic CORS question.

Comment: I have an application (running on domain A) which needs to send a soap Post request to a web service to another domain (domain B).
the ws receives only POST request with xml input.


I need a solution that does not ask permeation from B (its not mine and I can't control it).

Comment: Maybe I still don't understand what you're asking, but either domain B accepts and responds to POSTs from domain A or it doesn't. Without more esoteric information on the web service itself, I don't know how else we can help you.